# ItemDecoration not drawn on last cell

Tags: android

I have written a small snippet to show a vertical line and a little ball in each and every item of a RecyclerView.
But the last one or when there is 1 item only is never getting drawn.

My Decoration:

```
public class MarkerDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    Paint paint;

    public MarkerDecoration() {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#cccccc"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int childCount = parent.getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View v = parent.getChildAt(i);
            c.save();

            if (childCount > 1) {
                if (i == 0)
                    c.drawLine(v.getX() + v.getPaddingLeft(), v.getHeight() / 2 - v.getY(), v.getX() + v.getPaddingLeft(), v.getHeight(), paint);
                else if (i == childCount - 1)
                    c.drawLine(v.getX() + v.getPaddingLeft(), v.getY(), v.getX() + v.getPaddingLeft(), v.getY() - v.getHeight() / 2, paint);
                else
                    c.drawLine(v.getX() + v.getPaddingLeft(), v.getY(), v.getX() + v.getPaddingLeft(), v.getHeight() + v.getY(), paint);
            }

            c.drawCircle(v.getX() + v.getPaddingLeft(), v.getY() - v.getHeight() / 2, 8, paint);
            c.restore();
        }
    }
}
```

And the layout it is getting called on:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/line_item_paddings"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/line_item_text_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/line_item_paddings">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/post_date_row"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/line_item_text_padding"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/line_item_text_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/line_item_text_padding"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/line_item_text_padding"
        android:text="3 JUL"
        android:textColor="@color/light_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_row"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/post_date_row"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/amount_row"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/post_date_row"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/amount_row"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/line_item_text_padding"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/line_item_text_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/line_item_text_padding"
        android:text="GTX Telecom" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amount_row"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/line_item_text_padding"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/line_item_text_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/line_item_text_padding"
        android:text="54,00" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What I am missing here ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> or when there is 1 item only is never getting drawn.

take a look at this snippet from your code of the decoration class

```
if (childCount > 1) {
    if (i == 0)
        c.drawLine(v.getX() + v.getPaddingLeft(), v.getHeight() / 2 - v.getY(), v.getX() + v.getPaddingLeft(), v.getHeight(), paint);
    else if (i == childCount - 1)
        c.drawLine(v.getX() + v.getPaddingLeft(), v.getY(), v.getX() + v.getPaddingLeft(), v.getY() - v.getHeight() / 2, paint);
    else
        c.drawLine(v.getX() + v.getPaddingLeft(), v.getY(), v.getX() + v.getPaddingLeft(), v.getHeight() + v.getY(), paint);
}
```

the `c.drawline`s get executed only when the childCount is greater than 1, just change the if condition to `if(childCount >= 1)` That should fix this problem.

This answer atleast solves one of your problem ill still keep looking trying to find whats causing the decoration to not show on the last item, for the last item I suppose this line should executed

```
c.drawLine(v.getX() + v.getPaddingLeft(), v.getY(), v.getX() + v.getPaddingLeft(), v.getY() - v.getHeight() / 2, paint);
```

But I don't know exactly whats wrong with it

**EDIT**

I solved your 2nd problem too, the 2nd to last argument you pass to drawline `v.getY() - v.getHeight() / 2` you are essentially drawing a line starting from the top left corner of the view and ending it at somewhere above the view(about `v.getY() - v.getHeight()/2` exactly) just change this to `v.getY() + v.getHeight()/2` instead

this 2nd to last argument the one before the paint argument, is the float stopY so you are asking line to start from top left of view and end `v.getY() - v.getHeight()` above the view, which is out of this view's bounds and hence can't see the line.

So your fixed code would look like this

```
if (childCount >= 1) {
    if (i == 0)
        c.drawLine(v.getX() + v.getPaddingLeft(), v.getHeight() / 2 - v.getY(), v.getX() + v.getPaddingLeft(), v.getHeight(), paint);
    else if (i == childCount - 1)
        c.drawLine(v.getX() + v.getPaddingLeft(), v.getY(), v.getX() + v.getPaddingLeft(), v.getY() + v.getHeight() / 2, paint);
    else
        c.drawLine(v.getX() + v.getPaddingLeft(), v.getY(), v.getX() + v.getPaddingLeft(), v.getHeight() + v.getY(), paint);
}

   c.drawCircle(v.getX() + v.getPaddingLeft(), v.getY() + v.getHeight() / 2, 8, paint);
```

Comment: Thanks for aswering. The `childCount > 1` is correct. It happens when the list has only 1 item, thus, I only need to show the circle, no line at all.

Comment: And the line you mention is getting executed, I just don't know why it is not drawing correctly, I'm not sure if it is a mis-measure problem... Thanks again

Comment: Also I solved your 2nd problem too, the 2nd to last argument you pass to drawline `v.getY() - v.getHeight() / 2` you are essentially drawing a line starting from the top left corner of the view and ending it at somewhere above the view(about `v.getY() - v.getHeight()/2` exactly) just change this to `v.getY() + v.getHeight()/2` instead

Comment: this 2nd to last argument the one before the paint argument, is the `float stopY` so you are asking line to start from top left of view and end `v.getY() - v.getHeight()` above the view, which is out of this view's bounds and hence can't see the line. Ill be adding this to the answer

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari Also an upvote would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Thank you so much ! Changing both the subtraction to sum worked, as you described above !

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari if it solved your question then select it as the right answer to mark it resolved

Comment: Sure, I'd just ask you to put after the **edit** session above the entire correct code, if you may, to make it clear to people !

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari ok !